# Disable jQuery UI sortable in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, google-chrome-extension

I'm creating a chrome extension (which i'm new at) which disables sortable in a matched URL when a page is loaded and when the extension button itself is clicked.
My background script, on click (browserAction) sends a message to my content scripts (which is defined in the manifest as

```
"js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "jquery-ui.min.js", "content.js"]
```

content.js has a listener for the browser action (which works) and can run jQuery fine (e.g I tested a basic append to some text on the page - which works)

however when I try

```
$(".isSortable").sortable("disable");
```

I get

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: cannot call methods on sortable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'disable'
```

which is strange because if i run $(".isSortable").sortable("disable"); in the console it correctly disables the sorting on the page.

But If I change it to

```
$(".isSortable").sortable();
$(".isSortable").sortable("disable");
```

Then the error goes away, but the selected class is still sortable - can anyone shed a light on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: While we can *guess*, if you are going to show an error that says: "Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage": Then you should include the relevant code shown inside an actual `runtime.onMessage` listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your table to be initialized with sortable feature disabled, you should use

```
$(".isSortable").sortable({
  disabled: true
});
```

the `.sortable("disable");` can only be used after initialization.

Reference: [Official Document](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-disabled)